# What is the logical structure of this proof about closed sets and convergent sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, logic, proof-explanation

$\require{enclose}$
The proof below is from Introduction to Real Analysis by Rosenlicht,

> Let $S$ be a subset of a metric space $E$. Then $S$ is closed if and
> only if, whenever $p_1$,$p_2$,$p_3$,$\dots$ is a sequence of points of
> S that is convergent in $E$, we have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} p_n$
> $\in$ $S$.
>
> Suppose that $S$ is closed and that $p_1$,$p_2$,$p_3$,$\dots$ is a
> sequence of points of $S$ that converges to a point $p$ of $E$.  We
> must show that $p$ $\in$ $S$.  If this is not so, we have $p$ $\in$
> $\mathscr C S$.  Since $\mathscr C S$ is open, there is some
> $\epsilon$>0 such that $\mathscr C S$ contains the entire open ball of
> center $p$ and radius $\epsilon$.  Thus if $N$ is a positive integer
> such that d($p$, $p_n$) < $\epsilon$ whenever $n$ > $N$, we have $p_n$
> $\in$ $\mathscr C S$ whenever $n$ > $N$, a contradiction.  This shows
> that $p$ $\in$ $S$ and proves the "only if" part of the theorem.
>
> To prove the "if" part, suppose $S$ $\subset$ $E$ is not closed.  Then
> $\mathscr C S$ is not open, and there exists a point $p$ in $\mathscr C S$
> such that any open ball of center $p$ contains points of $S$.
> Hence for each positive integer $n$ we can choose $p_n$ $\in$ $S$ such
> that d($p$, $p_n$) < $1/n$.  Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} p_n$ =
> $p$, with each $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{p_n \in \mathscr C S\,and\,p \in S}$ $p_n\in S\,and\,p \notin S$  .
>
> This shows that if the hypothesis on convergent sequences holds, then
> $S$ must be closed, completing the proof of the "if" part, and hence
> of the whole theorem.

I understand that to prove a statement of the form $P \iff Q$ it's necessary to show $P \implies Q$ and $Q \implies P$.  In the above theorem, let's call the statements:
$$X := S\,is\,closed.$$
$$ Y := p_1,p_2,p_3,\dots\,is\,a\,sequence\,of\,points\,of\,S\,that\,converges\,to\,a\,point\,p\,of\,E.$$
$$Z := \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} p_n
\in S. $$

In terms of those, the theorem is $X \iff Y \land Z$ so it's necessary to show $X \implies Y \land Z$ and $Y \land Z \implies X$.

The "only if" part of the theorem is $Y \land Z \implies X$ and the proof is of the form:

$$ Assume\, X \land Y \\  \lnot Z \implies Y \land \lnot Y\\ \therefore\,Z$$

The "if" part of the theorem is $X \iff Y \land Z$ and the proof is of the form:

$$ \lnot X \implies \lnot Y \land Z $$

I don't understand how this proof is valid. My questions are:

1. The "only if" part seems to be by contradiction.  In a proof by contradiction, you're supposed to assume that the antecedant is false, in this case $Y \land Z$.  But here only $Z$ is assumed false.  Is that OK because a false $Z$ makes $Y \land Z$ false as well?

2. The "if" part of the proof seems to be by contrapositive?  In a proof by contrapositive, you're supposed to assume the consequent is false and derive that the antecedent is false, in this case $\lnot X \implies \lnot(Y \land Z)$. But here only $\lnot Y \land Z$ is shown to be false.
3. I doubt I got the logical forms of the theorem or proofs right.  What are their logical forms?

Comment: You're missing the "whenever" part, which acts as shorthand for "for all sequences, if ... then ...". With $X,Y,Z$ as you've defined them, the form of the theorem is $X\iff \forall \vec p (Y(\vec p)\implies Z(\vec p))$.

Comment: You right-hand side ($ Y \wedge Z$) should be $ Y \implies Z $ (so that the entire proposition becomes $X \iff (Y \implies Z$)), since what you really want to prove is that (F is closed) $ \iff $ (if $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^n \subset E$ is a sequence of points converging to $p \in E$, then $p \in S$). Basically, the problem here is that $Y$ is not really a logical sentence (you can't say if it is true or false)

Comment: Didn't see @Karl comment while I was writing, that's exactly the same expression (I just transformed the "for all sequences $p$ s.t. $Y(p)$ holds then $Z(p)$ holds" into "if $p$ is a sequence that satisfies $Y(p)$ then $Z(p)$ holds"

Comment: @david_sap Good insight about Y is not really a logical sentence (you can't say if it is true or false

Comment: This pattern of implicitly expressing a "forall" by introducing new symbols in the antecedent of a conditional (in this case the $p_1,p_2,...$ in the "whenever ..." phrase) is pretty common in mathematical writing.

Answer (score 1):

> $X$ := $S$ is closed
>  $Y$ := $p_1,p_2,p_3,\dots$ is a sequence of points in $S$  that converges to a point in $E$
>  $Z$ := $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} p_n \in S$
>
> > Let $S$ be a subset of a metric space $E$. Then $S$ is closed if and
> > only if, whenever $p_1$,$p_2$,$p_3$,$\dots$ is a sequence of points of
> > S that is convergent in $E$, we have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} p_n$
> > $\in$ $S$.

As pointed out by Karl, the above theorem translates as $$X\leftrightarrow\forall \vec p \:\big(Y(\vec p)\to Z(\vec p)\big).$$ This is actually logically equivalent [to](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(X%7E4%7E6p(Yp%7E5Zp))%7E4(%7E6p(X%7E1Yp%7E5Zp))%7E1(%7E3X%7E5%7E7p(Yp%7E1%7E3Zp))) the conjunction of $$\forall \vec p \:\big(X\land Y(\vec p)\to Z(\vec p)\big)\tag1$$ **and** $$\lnot X\to  \exists \vec p \:\big(Y(\vec p)\land\lnot Z(\vec p)\big).\tag2$$

> > Suppose that $S$ is closed and that $p_1$,$p_2$,$p_3$,$\dots$ is a
> > sequence of points of $S$ that converges to a point $p$ of $E$.  We
> > must show that $p$ $\in$ $S$.
>
> > proves the "only if" part of the theorem

This is statement $(1)$ from above: $$\forall \vec p \:\big(X\land Y(\vec p)\to Z(\vec p)\big).\tag1$$

> > To prove the "if" part, suppose $S$ $\subset$ $E$ is not closed. Then
>
> > there exists
>
> > $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} p_n = p$, with each $p_n \in S$ and $p\not\in S.$
>
> > completing the proof of the "if" part

This is statement $(2)$ from above: $$\lnot X\to  \exists \vec p \:\big(Y(\vec p)\land\lnot Z(\vec p)\big).\tag2$$

---

Referring to the original text screen-captured below, note that you have mistranscribed

> > Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} p_n = p,$ with each $p_n\in \boldsymbol S$ and $p\boldsymbol{\not\in S}$

as

> > Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} p_n = p,$ with each $p_n \in \boldsymbol{\mathscr C S}$ and $p \boldsymbol{\in S}$

and that the excerpt I used above is actually the corrected one.

[image]